# Return to a view along with javascript message in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-4

I want to redirect my controller to a view along with a certain condition so my code goes somewhat like this:

```
$temp=getSomeResponseFromMethod();
if($temp==1)
return View:: make('page1');
else
return View:: make ('page2');
```

Now in page1 and page2 blade pages , I want to pass javascript alerts like "Hey successful operation". I know I can pass variables using with , however not so sure how I can create an alert using that.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote, I would have appreciated if an answer would have been provided along with that

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via the blade templates. Pass global variables to the JS like this in your template (preferably in the header):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// <![CDATA[
var yourVariable = {{$temp}};
// ]]>
</script>
```

Then inside some of your JS files or inline script (less preferable):

```
if (yourVariable == 1) {
 // do something
}
```

This way you could separate the frontend code from your backend code, just by passing variables to the JS. You could even create a container object for your variables like that, so you wont pollute the global namespace.